# Where to ask about mobile phone tethering and physics behind it?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I struggle to find on topic site to ask my question. It has to do with mobile phone tethering, so here is link to my attempt to ask it on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58090/does-punkt-mp02-tethering-cost-money):

> I am in US and I bought Punkt MP02, and it works on AT&T. This phone has tethering option. I just go to settings, click "Turn on Tethering" and that's it, it just works. Now, I know that US carriers charge for tethering, and you would have to go online or in store to subscribe to this feature to be available on the smartphone, and pay $30-$400 for it monthly, depending on how much MB/GB limit you want. But I did not do any of that with my Punkt. I just turned on tethering in my settings and it worked.
>
> So, does/can AT&T know I started using tethering and will charge me for that, or the kind of tethering which is implemented in Punkt, perhaps, hardware supported, somehow, and therefore makes it impossible for AT&T to figure out I'm using tethering, hence no charges will appear on my next bill?
>
> Edit (after this question was marked off-topic):
>
> To clarify. I fully understand nobody has incite on how AT&T does their business. But my minimal, basic understanding of how electromagnetic waves work I suspect that it is possible to give an answer to the question of "according to laws of physics - more specifically that subset of physics which has to deal with electromagnetic waves - is it physically possible for a cellular network carrier to determine whether somebody uses tethering on their mobile device without their "approval" (aka. their subscription plan) and charge them money for that?".

Can somebody suggest me a site where this question is not off-topic?

Should I ask this on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) because Punkt is running on Android? But my question is not specifically about Android, it's about the physics of tethering.

Should I ask it on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)? Feels off topic there, too. Physics SE does not even have a tag for "tethering".

Comment: It sounds all very specific and on the edge of what the agreement you have with your telco provider allows you. I think it better fits on an Hackers forum as you basically ask for a black-hat hack. None of the SE sites cater for that.

Comment: This is not really physics. It only counts in the sense that everything in the universe is physics, but the [Physics.SE] mods don't quite see their site's scope in that way.